# how to check a loop when finished adding data to firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of fruit lists

```
 Object.keys(fruit).forEach(function (item) {
                   
                        firebase.firestore().collection("FruitBasket").doc().set({
                            name:item.name,
                            width:item.width,
                            height:item.height
                        }).then(() => {
                                //complete add one fruit
                        })
                      }
                 })
```

how can i check when the whole **Fruit Basket** is added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't know upfront the number of asynchronous calls that you want to run in parallel, you should use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
  const promises = [];

  Object.keys(fruit).forEach((item) => {          
    promises.push(
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('FruitBasket')
      .add({
        name: item.name,
        width: item.width,
        height: item.height,
      }));
  });

  Promise.all(promises)  // Returns a single Promise
  .then(() => {
    //  Here the whole Fruit Basket is added
  })
```

---

PS1: Note that instead of `doc().set(...)` you can do [`add(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference?authuser=0#add).

---

PS2: Note the possibility to use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0#batched-writes). Potential drawback: it has a limit of 500 docs, which `Promise.all()` doesn't have.

Comment: Instead of `Array#forEach()` and `Array#push()`, you could use `Array#map()`.